# Fork Dash - New coin problems

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, altcoin-development, dash

Currently I am doing my final year project by forking the Dash code and generate a new coin from that. I had read lots of tutorial online and follow the steps as well. First, I had generate the genesis block using the genesisH0. I replace the alert pub key, genesis block, merkle root and some code. However, I cannot mining with the genesis block 0.

The QT program is stop at the beginning and stated synchronizing header and the another PC stated connecting to peer. I had check the peer info as well. Both of the PC show that there are connect to each other. But there was a weird thing, which was the port number associate with each of the IP. The port number is random as well. Anyone can help me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the port number, the outgoing port will usually be random but on each PC it is connecting to it should be static.